# Why there is an error in var in line 44 (var finalURL = formURL + formData; and line 46

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, syntax-error, google-forms

When I am saving or running this it shows

> syntax error unexpected token var in line 44 var finalURL = formURL + formData;

I followed this step by step from a tutorial and that one ran smoothly. But I am running into this error even though all looks good to me.

It shows no error when I place these two variables above `formUrl` and `formData` but will that be ok to do?

```
function autoEntry() {
 var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var wrkSht = wrkBk.getSheetByName("Data");

 var formURL = "";
 var formData = "";

 var email = "";
 var wherefound = "";
 var contest = "";
 var contest2 = "";
 var p1name = "";
 var phone = "";
 var email1 = "";
 var college = "";
 var team = "";
 var add = "";
 var p2name = "";
 var p2phone = "";
 var p2email = "";


 var noOfrows = 11;

 for (i=2;i<=noOfrows;i++)
 {
   email = wrkSht.getRange("A" + i).getDisplayValue();
   wherefound = wrkSht.getRange("B" + i).getDisplayValue(); 
   contest = wrkSht.getRange("C" + i).getDisplayValue();
   contest2 = wrkSht.getRange("D" + i).getDisplayValue();
   p1name = wrkSht.getRange("E" + i).getDisplayValue();
   phone = wrkSht.getRange("F" + i).getDisplayValue();
   email1 = wrkSht.getRange("G" + i).getDisplayValue();
   college = wrkSht.getRange("I" + i).getDisplayValue();
   team = wrkSht.getRange("I" + i).getDisplayValue();
   add = wrkSht.getRange("J" + i).getDisplayValue();
   p2name = wrkSht.getRange("H" + i).getDisplayValue();
   p2phone = wrkSht.getRange("F" + i).getDisplayValue();
   p2email = wrkSht.getRange("G" + i).getDisplayValue();

formURL ="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1CBfK0vGAJhU2zUlAYQS75qX0a79n52o_j5xRobd9ElM/formResponse?&pageHistory=0,1,2"
 formData = "&emailAddress=" + email + "&entry.985288382=" + wherefound + "&entry.1403417779=" + contest + "&entry.1403417779=" + contest2 + "&entry.840653442=" + p1name + "&entry.333445391=" + phone + "&entry.1710226101" + email1 + "&entry.1025973123=" + college + "&entry.1833616786=" + team + "&entry.1627866442=" + add + "entry.2057643731=" + p1name + "&entry.1510242317=" + phone + "&entry.1096702233" + email1 + "&entry.1638965943=" + p2name + "&entry.699293629=" + p2phone + "&entry.811372241=" + p2email +

 var finalURL = formURL + formData;

 var options = {
   "method": "post"
  };
 UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalURL, options);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `+` at the end of line where you are assigning `formData`.

`formData = "&emailAddress=" + email + "&entry.985288382=" + wherefound + "&entry.1403417779=" + contest + "&entry.1403417779=" + contest2 + "&entry.840653442=" + p1name + "&entry.333445391=" + phone + "&entry.1710226101" + email1 + "&entry.1025973123=" + college + "&entry.1833616786=" + team + "&entry.1627866442=" + add + "entry.2057643731=" + p1name + "&entry.1510242317=" + phone + "&entry.1096702233" + email1 + "&entry.1638965943=" + p2name + "&entry.699293629=" + p2phone + "&entry.811372241=" + p2email +`

Removing that should solve the error.

Comment: did and worked. Thank you so much. i was staring at that line from half an hour and totally ignoring the +